# How do you properly align a span horizontally central and vertically central in an li using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

How do you properly align a span both horizontally and vertically central in an li using CSS?

There's probably more than one way to do it(?) but what is the correct or best way to do it and ensure it is truly centred horizontally and vertically?

There are similar questions in other scenarios but not that work with the li.

This is what I have so far...

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/list.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="aList">
            <li><span>Bob Smith</span></li>
            <li><span>Joe</span></li>
            <li><span>Lisa Henson</span></li>
            <li><span>Freddy Tallman</span></li>
            <li><span>Sarah Jones</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
}


#aList {
    
    height: auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 5px, 5px, 5px, 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

    #aList li {
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 50px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px green solid;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

        #aList li span {
            border: 1px blue solid;
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)'s [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property (for vertical align) and [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property (for horizontal align):

```css
body {}

#aList {
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px, 5px, 5px, 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#aList li {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px green solid;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#aList li span {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="css/list.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="aList">
      <li><span>Bob Smith</span></li>
      <li><span>Joe</span></li>
      <li><span>Lisa Henson</span></li>
      <li><span>Freddy Tallman</span></li>
      <li><span>Sarah Jones</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There looks like there's slightly more space on the right of the text than on the left? Is that a side-effect of justifying the content, rather than true aligning?

Comment: @D.Man I don't see slightly more space on the right. It might be different for me. Would you like to send a screenshot?

Comment: It may be just my eyes.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `text-align: center;` on the `li span`, and you'll have to set the top margin accordingly for each to get it down from the top, as well as using a `line-height`

Answer (score -2):

The use of flex-box was awesome only that there is so many unnecessary use of css lines. I edited them and hope things look better now.
I could have added a comment but my star is too low for that.

```css
body {
}


#aList {
    height: auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 5px, 5px, 5px, 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}

    #aList li {
        min-height: 50px;
        border: 1px green solid;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

        #aList li span {
            border: 1px blue solid;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/list.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="aList">
            <li><span>Bob Smith</span></li>
            <li><span>Joe</span></li>
            <li><span>Lisa Henson</span></li>
            <li><span>Freddy Tallman</span></li>
            <li><span>Sarah Jones</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```